# problem in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I have recently dual booted ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS alongside window 7 in my dell laptop from live usb flash drive.

The dual boot was working until I deleted empty partition (not ubuntu or window partition) and merged it with anouther. When I restarted it displayed the following:

```
error : unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Did I mess with my OS or what?
How can I recover to have dual boot again?

Comment: pls update your partition snapshots,that would help a little bit. Generally deleting a partition disturbs the partition table.

Comment: can't do that because comp is not booting to any OS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have accidentally erased the partition which grub (the boot loader) is installed into.

The suggestion is to run Ubuntu with your usb flash drive without installing Ubuntu. And when you are shown the desktop, please run the following commands in the terminal (you should have internet connected).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

And select Recommended repair, It will take sometime and then when it finishes, restart your machine. Remove the usb flash drive and boot again. This will restore your grub boot loader.

Comment: I don't know  why but I can't connect my wifi in ubuntu.

Comment: it worked but it only gets me into windows directly..

Comment: what happened to ubuntu..

Comment: See this for the wifi problem.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/608043/wifi-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit/608077#608077